# What's the proper way of exception handling in the ktor Network socket?

Tags: kotlin, ktor, ktor-client

I'm looking for the possible exception on each API in "TcpSocketBuilder" or "UDPSocketBuilder".

for example, the "connect" function in the TCP socket throws "ConnectException" when trying to connect an invalid address, but the api documentation never discusses this possible exception.

```
connect(
    remoteAddress: SocketAddress,
    configure: SocketOptions.TCPClientSocketOptions.() -> Unit = {}
)
```

Api document:
https://api.ktor.io/ktor-network/io.ktor.network.sockets/connect.html

I see that Ktor sockets are using java.nio under the hood, so should I look for the java.nio api doc for exceptions?

Comment: The actual exceptions depend on the target (`JVM` or `POSIX`). You can refer to Java Networking (NIO) API docs for JVM.